# Transient simulation of a Gaussian wave packet using time dependent Liouville-von Neumann equation in center mass coordinates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, density-functional-theory

I am working on a transient simulation of a Gaussian wave packet using time dependent Liouville-von Neumann equation in center mass coordinates. For discretization of diffusion term, I have used Crank Nicolson scheme. Can any one explain how to incorpotate the fixed and open boundary conditions using this scheme? I want to implement fixed boundaries using Fermi distribution function in real space.

Comment: Follow through the Crank-Nicolson derivation but replace the $x_{-1}$ and $x_{n+1}$ terms with whatever you want the boundaries to be - these can be updated dynamically. In the case of open BCs the standard solution is to use [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Some_Green.27s_function_solutions_in_1D) solutions at the boundaries.

Comment: Thank you lemon for your valueable suggestion. Can you please write some derivation for the open and fixed boundaries using Green's function approach.....!!!!

Comment: 3 years is long to not get an answer, you can copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com now that Materials.SE is live.